# How to do top-of-tree development with Swift Package Manager and XCode?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

So I am working on two packages in tandem, where Package A depends on Package B.

```
Package A -> Package B
```

Each package is in a separate git repository, and I would like to avoid having to push changes from Package B to remote every time I make a change just to be able to use it with Package A.

Using the documentation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#top-of-tree-development), I have put Package B in edit mode like so:

```
$ cd /path/to/package_a/checkout/location
$ swift package edit PackageB --path /path/to/package_b/checkout/location
```

Based on my understanding, this *should* basically tell SPM to reference the local checkout of the package, at the specified `--path`, rather than managing its own checkout.

But the thing is, if I open package A in XCode:

```
open /path/to/package_a/checkout/location/Package.swift
```

And I go to "show source" on Package B, it's showing me the checkout in the derived data folder.

So it seems like XCode is not observing the edit mode configuration provided by SPM?  Or else how do I achieve having XCode point to a local checkout of a package rather than the default behavior?